# Swift 4 with Firebase database OR Firestore read/write

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am fairly new at iOS development and very new with database integration. In short, I am trying to create a water tracker. In both the Realtime Database AND Firestore, I can write new data and update data. When I close and reopen the application, the console prints the current stored value. I am struggling with pulling that value into a label. My dictionary is setup (for example) ["Cups of Water:" x], I would like to put the value of x into the label but I can't seem to pull that value in.

The other issue I cannot seem to overcome is appending what the database has stored, instead of a complete overwrite. When I close/reopen the application, the console prints "15" (for example), excluding my issue with being able to import the value into the label, if I touch an add cup button, it will overwrite the value of "15" and now display "1".

This is clearly something that I am not adding correctly and I have some ideas where the issue lies but I can't quite see it. Any input is greatly appreciated!

The code below is specific to the Firestore. I can get a similar process working in the Realtime Database (by using the correct syntax). 
Code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var totalWaterLabel: UILabel!

var ref: DocumentReference? = nil
var variableCupsOfWater = 0
var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
var waterListener: FIRListenerRegistration!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

@IBAction func addOnePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    variableCupsOfWater += 1
    totalWaterLabel.text = String(variableCupsOfWater)
    saveToFirestore()
}
@IBAction func addTwoPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    variableCupsOfWater += 2
    totalWaterLabel.text = String(variableCupsOfWater)
    saveToFirestore()
}
@IBAction func addFourPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    variableCupsOfWater += 4
    totalWaterLabel.text = String(variableCupsOfWater)
    saveToFirestore()
}

func saveToFirestore() {
    let _: DocumentReference? = nil
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    let uid = user!.uid

    db.collection("By User").document("\(uid)").updateData([
        "Cups Of Water": "\(totalWaterLabel.text!)",
        "Date": NSDate()
    ]) { err in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error adding document: \(err)")
        } else {
            print("Document added")
        }
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener({ (auth, user) in
        print(Auth.auth().currentUser as Any)
    })
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    let uid = user!.uid


    db.collection("By User").document("\(uid)")
        .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
                    guard let querySnapshot = querySnapshot, querySnapshot.exists else {return}
            let myData = querySnapshot.data()
            let currentWaterTotal = myData["Cups of Water:"] as? String ?? ""
            let combinedCups = ("\(currentWaterTotal)") + self.totalWaterLabel.text!
            self.totalWaterLabel.text = "\(querySnapshot.data())"
            if let error = error {
                print("Error retreiving collection: \(error)")
            }else{

                print("Current data: \(String(describing: querySnapshot.data()))")
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you show the output of this statement: `print("Current data: \(String(describing: querySnapshot.data()))")`

Comment: Thank you for your response, when I run the app, I receive the following information in the console:

//My user (to ensure that the auth portion was working
Optional(<FIRUser: 0x60c0000d2830>)

//Current read from the database, from my last attempt
Current data: ["Date": 2017-10-06 13:21:59 +0000, "Cups Of Water": 3]

//Pressed add two cups of water and received the following values
Current data: ["Date": 2017-10-07 16:05:26 +0000, "Cups Of Water": 2]

//Print "document saved" if the save was successful.
Document added


Issue 1:

Comment: so you are saying that you are getting the info from db but unable to update on the `totalWaterLable`, right?

Comment: Yes, I tried everything (that I could think of) to pull the .data value from that dictionary and have it displayed in a label. I can either see the word "function" or the entire value of the snapshot, not just the part of it I want displayed.

Comment: what value do you want to display?can you please explain?

Comment: Of the dictionary values that I have set, I would only like to display the number after "Cups of Water". In the above example, I would like to display "2" in the label.

Comment: please try this: `self.totalWaterLabel.text = "\(currentWaterTotal)" `

Comment: The console displays:

Current data: ["Date": 2017-10-07 17:43:46 +0000, "Cups Of Water": 10]

But the label is blank upon load.

Comment: I think you need to remove `:` from this statement `myData["Cups of Water:"]`. Use just `myData["Cups of Water"]`

Comment: I removed the : and the label now displays nil. The console still displays "10" though.

Comment: You have to match the key exactly so I think you should try this: `myData["Cups Of Water"]` instead of `myData["Cups of Water:"]`

Comment: That was it! The label returns "Optional[10]". Is there a way for me to drop the Optional and the brackets?

Comment: use this : `if let cupsOfWater = myData["Cups Of Water"] as? String { self.totalWaterLabel.text = cupsOfWater }` , this is called optional binding syntax , you can learn more here : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much. I ma going to look through the documentation as well so I can get a better understanding. Thank you again!

Comment: I would like to mark your question as the answer as well.

Comment: Great, added the answer, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to match the key exactly so I think you should try this:

```
myData["Cups Of Water"]
```

instead of

```
myData["Cups of Water:"]
```

use this to safely unwrap the value from an optional:

```
if let cupsOfWater = myData["Cups Of Water"] as? String { 

          self.totalWaterLabel.text = cupsOfWater 

}
```

this is called `optional binding` syntax , you can learn more here

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html